# Spring REST Pageable / Query Parameters in Swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm trying to implement paging in my REST service.

TAKE 1:

```
public Page<Item> getPagedItems(Pageable pageable)
```

This is a known bug in SpringFox / Swagger where the Swagger page shows the wrong parameter names. Plus, I just want page & size options.

TAKE 2:

```
public Page<Item> getPagedItems(@RequestParam(name="page", required=true) int page, @RequestParam(name="page", required=true) int size)
```

This gives me the correct params, but it doesn't let me set the param descriptions or example values.

TAKE 3:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name="page", value="page description", required=true, example="0", dataType="int"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name="size", value="size description", required=true, example="10", dataType="int")
})
public Page<Item> getPagedItems(int page, int size)
```

This has yet ANOTHER bug where example="0" doesn't work, but every other value except that one works lol. If I change the datatype to String then it'll display the 0 example value, but then it'll let you put in anything in the text box. Also tried "0 ", "0.0", "0\0", etc. Stuff like that.

If I don't set examples, then Springfox throws an exception complaining about no examples lol. The closest thing I can do is put 0 for both with both blank. Ugh. Having 0 / 10 isn't a good option since the 0 doesn't work, but the 10 does.

Any idea how to get an example of 0 to work? Spring Fox doesn't seem to be too well supported, even for open source, so no response on GitHub.

Or some other way of having an example AND description?

Answer (score 0):

We created a inherited annotation and used that :

```
 @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "page",  dataTypeClass = int.class,defaultValue = "0", example = "0", paramType = "query", value = "Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "size", dataTypeClass = int.class ,example = "10", paramType = "query", value = "Number of records per page."),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "sort", allowMultiple = true, dataTypeClass=String.class, paramType = "query", value = "Sorting criteria in the format: property(,asc|desc). "
            + "Default sort order is ascending. " + "Multiple sort criteria are supported.")  
})
public @interface ApiPagingParams {

}
```

usage

```
@ApiPagingParams
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping("/entity") 
ResponseEntity<Page<...>> getSurveyEntityList(@ApiIgnore("see @ApiPagingParams") @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10) Pageable pageable,...)
```